# Excel VBA Vlookup with Ranges

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have vlookup formula that takes the value of A2 and returns the corresponding match found in my Lookup_Table in cell O2, this lookup continues for the rows underneath.

How would I modify this code to lookup a range of values in A:M, with the results placed in O:AA? Or do I have to manually code each column separately?

```
  With Sheets("Example")
    .Range("O2:O" & .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = _
        "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'Lookup_Table'!A:H,4,FALSE)),0,VLOOKUP(A2,'Lookup_Table'!A:H,4,FALSE))"
           .Range("O2:O" & .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value = _
        .Range("O2:O" & .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value 'Comment out if you'd like to leave the above formula in place
End With
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you explain it a little bit better please - perhaps with screenshots?  I find it rather confusing.  You are populating range E2:AX and taking value from A2?
Also, your formula `=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,Lookup_Table!B:I,4,FALSE)),0,VLOOKUP(B2,Lookup_Table!B:I,4,FALSE))` is redundant, you should be using something like `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Lookup_Table!A:H,4,FALSE),0)`

Comment: I appreciate your response I added a screenshot, hopefully it's less confusing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `Lookup_Table` = `'Lookup_Table'!A:H`, you could try something like:

```
With worksheets("Cross_Walk") ' Assumes Activeworkbook
    .Range("E2:H" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = _
        "=Iferror(VLOOKUP(A2,'Lookup_Table'!$A:$H,4,FALSE),0)"
    End With
```

- We assign the formula to range `E2:H?` where `?` is whatever the last row is determined to be.
- Excel observes relative and absolute references when assigning the same formula to a range of cells.
- So since `A2` in the VLOOKUP has a relative row and column reference (no $ signs), it will change to `B2` when the formula is entered in `F2` -- and so forth for the remaining columns and rows.
- Also, if you're going to test whether the result of the VLOOKUP is an error, and then conditionally assign either zero or the matching value, you may as well just use IFERROR in your formula -- rather than performing the VLOOKUP twice.

Comment: Sorry I was unable to get your example working. I modified my question and included a screen shot to simplify the question, does this make more sense now?

Comment: @user3596788 Okay, did it give you an error message? Did the code run okay but the formula/results were wrong? Based on the screenshot, the formula needs to match values in columns `A:M` (on the sheet in screenshot) to columns `A:H` of the worksheet `Lookup_Table` (a different sheet to the one shown in the screenshot), but the formula itself needs to go in columns `O:AA` on the worksheet shown -- is that correct? Also, do you really want to fill every row in the columns with the formula (it will likely make the spreadsheet quite slow, if there are 1 million rows to update/recalculate).

Comment: It works I put the wrong column range in initially. Regarding the performance I would expect 2-3k rows at most is there a better approach? Also, how do I return blank instead of 0 when no match is found?

Comment: In my opinion, if the code works fine for you, then there's no need to optimise it further. Also, if you want to return `blank` instead of `0`, try changing this line `"=Iferror(VLOOKUP(A2,'Lookup_Table'!$A:$H,4,FALSE),0)"` in the code to `"=Iferror(VLOOKUP(A2,'Lookup_Table'!$A:$H,4,FALSE),"""")"`. Technically, this doesn't make the cell blank, it puts a zero-length string into it -- but try it and see if it's okay for you.